# How do I stop Ubuntu 20.04 from asking me my password everytime I run the TOR service?

Tags: password, services, authentication, tor

I'm trying to run a script that uses TOR which restarts every time it finishes, but Ubuntu keeps asking me for my password.

Sorry, I'm very new to all of this. Thanks guys

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VUaff.jpg)

Comment: Edit your question and post the script

Comment: Include your script.  Normally you'd set up a tor service and have the *system* launch it for you at boot time rather than handling a 'restart tor' - there's usually no good reason to restart tor after you've used it.